# To what extent must we try to convince non-Jews to follow the 7 mitzvot?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, noachide-laws, noahidism

It is common to see Jews referring non-Jews who are interested in Judaism but not prepared to commit to following halakha to [Noahidism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noahidism) or simply to follow the 7 laws; however, it seems to me to be quite rare to see Jews actively proselytizing for Noahidism.

Are Jews supposed to encourage non-Jews to follow the 7 laws, or do we just hope that they'll do it? If we are supposed to encourage it, why is it so rare to see active engagement today?

Comment: how effective would such a campaign be? might wind up stirring hate against jews. best is to work on yourself, and try to make a good example. nonjews can see the truth when it's real.

Comment: @ray Who knows how effective it would be? Other religions proselytize. And even if it does end up stirring hate against Jews, how do you know that we aren't supposed to do it anyway?

Comment: as far as i know doesn't say anywhere in torah or gm that we should. there is one GM that relates of the open miracles when some Tana was giving a drasha during the Yom Tov every year and no nonjews in that town ever converted. the GM says there was a big anger on the nonjews in that town for that. anyone can fill in where that is?

Comment: @ray What about the requirement to [destroy idolatry](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1155089/jewish/-.htm)

Comment: @ray More importantly, whether it is practically applicable now or not is not relevant. We might say an obligation exists but now we shouldn't do it because of danger.

Answer (score 9):

Basing himself on Maimonides' ruling in Hilkhot Melakhim (8:10), "וכן צוה משה רבינו מפי הגבורה לכוף את כל באי העולם לקבל מצות שנצטוו בני נח" , the Lubavitcher Rebbe argued that it is incumbent upon each Jew to persuade the gentiles into observance of the seven Noahide laws. See Ha-Pardes vol. 59:9 (1985), pp. 7-11. Michael J. Broyde, “The Obligation of Jews to Seek Observance of Noahide Laws by Gentiles: A Theoretical Review,” in *Tikkun Olam: Social Responsibility in Jewish Thought and Law* (Jason Aronson, 1998) pp. 103-143, concludes that “the weight of halachic authority is contrary to this analysis.” See also the study by R. J. David Bleich in *Tikkun Olam*, who adopts an intermediate view.

Comment: have heard that reaching out to estranged Jews takes priority before this

Answer (score 5):

i would like to add another point, the Lubavitcher Rebbe also said that the reason this was not a common practice throughout the ages was because of jewish persecution. and that many halchic rulings were based on that, or coming in that spirit. however today when we are in a "malchus shel chessed", different times call for different measures.

see http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sichos-in-english/13/09.htm
beginning of second paragraph

see also http://www.sichosinenglish.org/books/sichos-in-english/26/01.htm part 5

In 1999 a book called ‘Kol Boei Olam’ (כל באי העולם)   (All Inhabitants of the World) was compiled by Rabbi Chaim Miller, and published by Vaad Migola L’Geulah, Brooklyn N.Y. It is a detailed compilation of the Lubavitcher Rebbe's teaching on Noachide Halacha and Hashkafa. Unfortunately it has not been translated into English.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you know where/when the Lubavitcher Rebbe said that?

Comment: @Daniel check the edit. still looking for a better, and clearer source.

Comment: He also says it in the Hapardes article that I quoted above