# Does Judaism believe in letting people know about judasim?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, chinuch-education

Let us say that proselytizing is against Judaism, what about just letting people know that there is a religion called Judaism and tell them a little bit about it just to put it out there for them, to tell them, if you are interested this may make your life meaningful? Not encouraging them to join.

And at the end of the day those non-jews that search meaning. The seven noahide laws will definitely not be enough for them. Judaism itself has so much more to it so maybe we should tell them about it.

Like maybe just putting up a billboard that says "interested in Judaism call 1800....."

Comment: "And at the end of the day those non-jews that search meaning. The seven noahide laws will definitely not be enough for them." Why not? There is a whole community of people who dedicate their lives to observing the 7 Noahide laws.

Comment: I know I agree but if you ever speak to these concerts you hear them say they're so happy they found this because that was not enough

Comment: Duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30545/1713 ? Maybe this one: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/17635/1713 ?

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I am saying more just let them know don't proysletize

Comment: @Daniel is it better now maybe

Comment: Why am I being downloaded what is wrong with this question where is the justice did the moderators please speak up

Comment: When do you download somebody there is a pop-up that comes and says please comment as to what you don't like about this question so if we want to keep this website and a healthy fashion please do that thank you so much

Comment: Unless you think it can be kept a secret, those who want to know will find out.  The converts I know sought out information, and had no trouble finding what they needed to get started.

Comment: I agree with you 100% just I'm referring to those people that don't really know what it is all about and don't want to even look for it because they're not interested when they find out what it's really about and they realize what they were missing just like anything new we learn we enjoy it once we know what it is

Comment: I have been on the receiving end of unsolicited "informing" of other religions' beliefs, including here on Mi Yodeya, and found it to be essentially equivalent to proselytizing from my point of view, despite the practitioners' protestations that they were not proselytizing.

Comment: This question would be a great deal more compelling if you would [edit] in support for your assertions that "proselytizing is against Judaism" and that "The seven noahide laws will definitely not be enough for [non-Jews]."

Comment: @menachem, If you want to write questions that the community deems valuable (which voting is an indication of), I recommend that you take a look at the guidelines in the ["H0w to Ask" FAQ entry](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and then look at questions that attract positive attention to see how they implement what's written there.

Comment: @menachem so is your real question "is gentle proselytizing ok?"?  Also, see Isaac's comments about how to improve this question.

Comment: Not at all proselytizing means when you go up to people and your encouragement to join your religion. This is your hanging up a few signs to just let people know not encouraging that you're not telling him this is for you just by the way if you're interested we have this very different

Answer (score 1):

Yehoshua translated Torah in 70 languages See Gemara Sota [35b](http://dtorah.com/otzar/shas_soncino.php?ms=Sotah&df=35b)
Torah has never been a secret religion. There are throughout the world secret religions, really very different.
I never encountered someone complaining that Torah knowledge is inaccessible.
The matan Tora is not a secret, the practice of Judaism is not secret.,
Jews do not hide.
In Gemara Sota we can see that Tora was offered and they do not care about it. Noweday there is a problem, 2 bans, as @hazoriz wrote based on Gemara Sanhedrin 59a. A prohibition for the non-Jew to learn, and a prohibition for the Jew to teach. This not for who want to convert See Yore Dea [268](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6770).

Answer (score 1):

In Judaism there is an idea **only** to teach them the 7 laws

[Rambam melachim 10](http://m.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188355/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-10.htm)

I understand that these laws are when non Jews are living in Isreal when it is ruled by Jews

Halacha 9

> A gentile who studies the Torah is obligated to die. **They should only be involved in the study of their seven mitzvot**.
>
> Similarly, a gentile who rests, even on a weekday, observing that day as a Sabbath, is obligated to die. Needless to say, he is obligated for that punishment if he creates a festival for himself.
>
> The general principle governing these matters is: They are not to be allowed to originate a new religion or create mitzvot for themselves based on their own decisions. They may either become righteous converts and accept all the mitzvot or retain their statutes without adding or detracting from them.
>
> If a gentile studies the Torah, makes a Sabbath, or creates a religious practice, a Jewish court should beat him, punish him, and inform him that he is obligated to die. However, he is not to be executed.

*On the other hand*

Halacha 10

> We should not prevent a gentile who desires to perform one of the Torah's mitzvot in order to receive reward from doing so, provided he performs it as required. If he brings an animal to be sacrificed as a burnt offering, we should receive it.
>
> If a gentile who observes the seven mitzvot gives charity, we should accept it from him. It appears to me that it should be given to the Jewish poor for the gentile may derive his sustenance from the Jews and they are commanded to support him if necessary. In contrast, if an idolater gives charity, we should accept it from him and give it to the gentile poor

See [https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/האיסור_ללמד_תורה_לנכר](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%93_%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%99)
And https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=8010