# Noachides: are Jews responsible for their spiritual support?

Tags: gentiles, torah-study, noachide-laws

Are Jews responsible for helping non-Jews learn of and follow the seven commandments given to Noachides?  Is it a mitzvah for Jews? I recall hearing the Lubavitcher Rebbe speak in favor of this.  But other than rabbis answering questions of individual Noachides, I don't see how we've give any guidance.  The Talmud has much to say about what the seven commandments say and mean (in Yevamos, I believe), but we are forbidden to teach Talmud to non-Jews. So are there any contemporary rabbis who have addressed this?

Comment: Excellent question; I hope you get good answers

Comment: A start; not sure about quality: http://www.jlaw.com/Articles/noach2.html

Comment: Regarding your last point, the Gemara Sanhedrin states explicitly that gentiles may learn their 7 mitzvot.

Comment: "how we've give any guidance": did you mean "how we've given any guidance" or "how we'd give any guidance"?

Comment: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30545/to-what-extent-must-we-try-to-convince-non-jews-to-follow-the-7-mitzvot

Comment: @wfb this is a dupe

Comment: Know you [Rabbi Eliah Ben Amozeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elijah_Benamozegh)?